# How to run cron-like scripts on Django?

Tags: python, django

To give you a little brief about what I'm tying to do ->
I'm building a timed-contest app which expires at a set datetime.
So basically I want a script which queries my model and changes some values according to busines logic **periodically**

How would you do this in django ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use celery.

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: I know its too late for this query, but i am facing cron related problems in my project. I have implemented celery in my django project, but now I want to run celery as a background process. For this docs suggest use supervisior. But supervisor is not compatible with python3.6, it only supports python2. So could you please suggest how can I use celery to run in background?

Answer (score 6):

You wouldn't. You'd use cron to run a [standalone script](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/) or [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: Oh come on, you know I don't know Unix !

Comment: What if I was using Windows, would that make it two right tools for the job? Isn't abstraction a great virtue of modern software ? Is there no pythonic way of doing it ?

Comment: @Zach Wild: A shell script is Pythonic.  It's the right tool.  Your windows batch scheduler works very much like cron, and can use Django management commands perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I've decided to use cron.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at django-cron
http://code.google.com/p/django-cron/

It takes advantage of Django being a long-run process and spawn a Timer thread in a fixed interval. The source code of this plugin is small and easy to understand as well.

Comment: There's no download on that page?

Comment: I wanna try this out, this seems closest to what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time I had similiar issue.
I used then kronos.py module from TurboGears framework:

http://sourceforge.net/p/turbogears1/code/7354/tree/projects/TGScheduler/trunk/tgscheduler/kronos.py